# Selenium Python webdriver: driver.get() won't accept a variable?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to write an automated test script that will perform a set of actions for multiple URL's. The reason I am trying to do this is because I am testing a web application with multiple front-end interfaces that are functionally exactly the same, so if I can use a single test script to run through all of them and make sure the basics are in order, this saves me a lot of time in regression testing when the codebase changes.

My current code is as follows:

```
# initialize the unittest framework
import unittest
# initialize the selenium framework and grab the toolbox for keyboard output
from selenium import selenium, webdriver
# prepare for the usage of remote browsers
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class Clubmodule(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
    #   load up the remote driver and tell it to use Firefox
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor="http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",    
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    def test_010_LoginAdmin(self):
        driver = self.driver
    #   prepare the URL by loading the list from a textfile
        with open('urllist.txt', 'r') as f:
            urllist = [line.strip() for line in f]
    #   Go to the /admin url
        for url in urllist:
        #   create the testurl  
            testurl = str(url) + str("/admin")
        #   go to the testurl
            driver.get("%s" %testurl)
        #   log in using the admin credentials

    def tearDown(self):
    #   close the browser
        self.driver.close()

# make it so!
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When I print the variable `testurl` I get the correct function, but when I try to run my script with Python it does not seem to convert `driver.get("%s" %testurl)` into `driver.get("actualurl")`.

I'm hoping it's a syntax issue but after trying all the variations I can come up with I'm starting to thing this is a limitation of Webdriver. Can this be done at all ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
driver.get(testurl)
```

I do not think string interpolation is required.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm starting to thing this is a limitation of Webdriver

certainly not.

the following code runs fine for me with Selenium 2.44:

```
from selenium import webdriver

testurl = 'http://example.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('%s' % testurl)
```